# Rotated icons "flicker" on redraw and appear upright for a few frames

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm coding an in-app camera and I have a little widget that contains the flash options. When a flash option is selected, the widget is a container with an icon inside representing the picked mode, no problem. When that container is tapped, the container opens to show a column with all the unselected options. That transformation is achieved with a simple `setState`.

#### Issue

When this flash widget is used when the screen is in portrait, there is no problem. When the screen is rotated however, every time the flash widget is expanded or shrunk, the icons blink in portrait mode before they're quickly rotated back according the screen. I've tried both with `Transform.rotate` and `RotatedBox`, the problem is the same. I use `NativeDeviceOrientation` to capture rotation.

Edit: here is a video of the problem with slightly altered code (no collapse of the widget) https://imgur.com/a/pNLp5HA

Any idea how I fix that flicker?

#### Code sample

The widget tree looks like this: Scaffold->SafeArea->NativeDeviceOrientationRead->Column->Padding->FlashWidget
The orientation is passed to the widget in its arguments. Here's the flash widget implementation, please note that `isOpenDialog`, `onSelect` and `orientation` are parameters passed for the build. `flashIcon` and `orientationRotations` are maps containing the icon and quarter rotations related to the type of flash and to the screen rotations respectively.

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 8),
    height: isDialogOpen ? 220 : 62,
    width: 62,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(35),
      ),
    ),
    child: !isDialogOpen
        ? GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => onSelect(selectedFlash),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
              child: Transform.rotate(
                filterQuality: FilterQuality.none,
                angle: (orientationRotations[orientation] ?? 0) * Math.pi / 2,
                child: Icon(
                  flashIcon[selectedFlash],
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(253, 253, 150, 1),
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: selectedFlash == FlashMode.auto ? 3 : 0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    onSelect(selectedFlash);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      filterQuality: FilterQuality.none,
                      angle: (orientationRotations[orientation] ?? 0) *
                          Math.pi /
                          2,
                      child: Icon(
                        flashIcon[selectedFlash],
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(253, 253, 150, 1),
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              for (final FlashMode flashMode in flashList)
                if (flashMode != selectedFlash)
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      onSelect(flashMode);
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: flashMode == FlashMode.auto ? 3 : 0,
                      ),
                      child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: Math.pi *
                            (orientationRotations[orientation] ?? 0) /
                            2,
                        child: Icon(
                          flashIcon[flashMode],
                          color: lightGreyGcaColor,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          ),
  );
```